# Como deixar textarea e button um do lado do outro?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Preciso implementar um textarea(mensagem) e um button(enviar) do seu lado direito, mas que seja liquido(100%), ou seja, se diminuir o tamanho da janela o textarea diminui e o button mantém o seu tamanho(60px por exemplo) e sempre colado no lado direito da janela.

É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser implementado com `calc`.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vQ8e/2/)

```
textarea {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

button {
    position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Essa solução é mais simples do que a anterior, o problema são os navegadores antigos. ;)

Comment: Há suporte parcial desde o IE 9, os browsers que contam têm suporte há bastante tempo: http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Cuidado com o suportes da CSS 3. Agora fica na decisão do Jefferson, qual se aplica melhor a necessidade dele.
Na minha resposta eu visei o funcionamento em todos os browser, porque infelizmente tem lugares usando IE 8 ou inferior que trava bastante o crescimento do CSS 3.

Comment: Sua resposta não está funcionando ainda @flpms

Comment: Bem isso que preciso. Obrigado @TiagoCésarOliveira, e flpms.. não consegui implementar com seu exemplo.. mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: Disponha @JeffersonAlison :)

Comment: De nada @JeffersonAlison, desculpa não ter trabalhado mais em algo funcional, fiquei longe de um computador devido ao feriado. Vou continuar buscando a solução em CSS 2.